# Rubymine editor not showing that gems are installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, rubymine

Despite the ruby and gems being pointed to correctly (I believe) as seen below:

[image]

[image]

Rubymine is not registering that the gem is installed.

Adding to the mystery: when running a file with RubyMine the gem appears to be found as when run via the RubyMine runner the output is:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/me/RubymineProjects/effective_testing_with_rspec_3/path_tests.rb
true
```

So it appears to be an issue mainly centered on editor. Any help would be super. I cannot find much info beyond suggestions to edit the Ruby SDK and Gems preferences but those appear correct to me. Thanks!

Comment: Try "Invalidate Caches/Restart.."

Comment: @kiddorails that looks like it works until RubyMine reindexes (about 15 seconds into the restart).